# 401 Unauthorized on Azure Function called form API Management

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

Good evening everyone,

I am constantly receiving a 401 error from API Management from an Azure Function, the thing is that I am using the following policy:

> ```
> <policies>
> <inbound>
>     <base />
>     <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://management.azure.com/" />
>     <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="managementResponse" timeout="20"
> ignore-error="true">
>         <set-url>https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/blablabla-bla-blalb-blablablablabla/resourceGroups/blabla-resourcegroup-blabla/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/DummyFunction-Test/functions/DummyFunction-Test?api-version=2018-11-01</set-url>
>         <set-method>PATCH</set-method>
>         <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
>             <value>application/json</value>
>         </set-header>
>         <set-body>@{
>             return new JObject(
>                 new JProperty("properties",
>                     new JObject(
>                         new JProperty("status", "disabled")
>                     )
>                 )
>             ).ToString();
>         }</set-body>
>     </send-request>
>     <choose>
>     <when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["managementResponse"]).StatusCode
>  == 401)">
>                 <return-response>
>                 <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
>                 <set-body>@{
>                         return "Authentication failed. Please check your Managed Identity setup.";
>                     }</set-body>
>             </return-response>
>         </when>
>    <when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["managementResponse"]).StatusCode
> == 403)">
>             <return-response>
>                 <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
>                 <set-body>@{
>                         return "Authorization failed. Managed Identity does not have sufficient permissions.";
>                     }</set-body>
>             </return-response>
>         </when>
>     </choose>
> </inbound>
> <backend>
>     <base />
> </backend>
> <outbound>
>     <base />
> </outbound>
> <on-error>
>     <base />
> </on-error> </policies>
> ```

By the way, using this policie I want to stop the function, so when I test the DummyFunction-Test I recived this:

[image]

[image]

In terms to solve the problem I checked a trace and I found the followings errors:

[image]

[image]

I've tried my best, but I can't stop the function. I've checked numerous configurations and my role is contributor. I would really appreciate any help. Can anybody help me?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `send-request` policy and not forward the request to the ARM API, you need to set the `authentication-managed-identity` policy within the `send-request` block instead.

So, your policy document should look something like this instead

```xml
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="managementResponse" timeout="20"
      ignore-error="true">
      <set-url>
        https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/blablabla-bla-blalb-blablablablabla/resourceGroups/blabla-resourcegroup-blabla/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/DummyFunction-Test/functions/DummyFunction-Test?api-version=2018-11-01</set-url>
      <set-method>PATCH</set-method>
      <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
      </set-header>
      <set-body>
      @{
        return new JObject(
          new JProperty("properties",
            new JObject(
              new JProperty("status", "disabled")
            )
          )
        ).ToString();
      }
      </set-body>
      <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://management.azure.com/" />
    </send-request>
    <choose>
      <when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["managementResponse"]).StatusCode
 == 401)">
        <return-response>
          <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
          <set-body>@{
            return "Authentication failed. Please check your Managed Identity setup.";
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
      </when>
      <when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables[" managementResponse"]).StatusCode
== 403)">
        <return-response>
          <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
          <set-body>@{
            return "Authorization failed. Managed Identity does not have sufficient permissions.";
            }</set-body>
        </return-response>
      </when>
    </choose>
  </inbound>
  <backend>
    <base />
  </backend>
  <outbound>
    <base />
  </outbound>
  <on-error>
    <base />
  </on-error>
</policies>
```

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/api-management/authentication-managed-identity-policy#use-managed-identity-in-send-request-policy) documentation for more information.